# How do I replace a double quote in json string and regular expressions?

Tags: json, regex, go

How do I replace a double quote in json string and regular expressions?

Input Json is:

```
"RegDateTime" : 1481641851263, "Code":"123213",....
```

and Output should be:

```
"RegDateTime" : "1481641851263", "Code":"123213",....
```

I want to fix only json key value that is RegDateTime.
Please suggest any regular expression and replace with double quote in go language.

Comment: That's the wrong way to think about it. That is a _number_. You're converting the number to a string... not just "replacing the quotes."

Comment: just convert to string.

Comment: @JeffMercado Other way around. He wants to convert numeric input to a string representation.

Comment: I have to fix the json string for Exception Routine.  I have to process two types of json at the same time

Comment: I don't think a regular expression is the way to go here. If you are trying to get your data into a Go struct I would make the "RegDateTime" an `interface{}` then use type assertion to convert the number to a string if need be

Answer (score 1):

```
func ReplaceAllNumber(json string)(string) {
    re := regexp.MustCompile("(:\\s*)(\\d+)(\\s*[,}\\]])")
    return re.ReplaceAllString(json, "$1\"$2\"$3")
}


func ReplaceNumberWithField(json string, fieldName string)(string) {
    regString := fmt.Sprintf("(\"%s\"\\s*:\\s*)(\\d+)(\\s*[,}\\]])", fieldName)

    re := regexp.MustCompile(regString)
    return re.ReplaceAllString(json, "$1\"$2\"$3")
}
```

[Run Online](https://play.golang.org/p/IzlfVWW1FQ)

Comment: Thanks chaoluo... What about this method??                                        re, _ := regexp.Compile("(RegDateTime\"):([0-9]+)")                             result:= re.ReplaceAllString(json, "$1:\"$2\"")

Comment: Do you need just replace a special field ?

Comment: ... my method is for replaceing all number field, so you can change to a special filed, that is easy.

Comment: OK, that is for special field

Comment: If this solves your problem, Could you please click the left arrow and accept the answer, I am short of 3 reputation ？thank you.